# Can I use asp.net identity with MVC 5 where back-end is web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, form-authentication

I have a web API which is written in java and on front end I am creating an Admin panel so to protect our restricted page I could use form based authentication however I heard that form based authentication has been deprecated(https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284380/is-formsauthentication-obsolete) from MVC 5 onward so Is there any alternative that I can use in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can install web api framework in mvc project with nuget. And install Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework,
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin. So you can use identity in MVC framework.

Comment: Thanks, I am handling with simply session.